# GStreamer reading camera resolution

Tags: gstreamer, ubuntu-14.04, v4l2

I'm trying to read resolutions supported by camera using GStreamer and plugin camerabin2. The problem is that I'm getting NULL.

```c
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define gstRef(element) { gst_object_ref(GST_OBJECT(element)); gst_object_sink(GST_OBJECT(element)); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  GstElement *m_camerabin = gst_element_factory_make("camerabin2", "camerabin2");  
  gstRef(m_camerabin);

  GstCaps *supportedCaps = 0;
    g_object_get(G_OBJECT(m_camerabin), "image-capture-supported-caps",
                  &supportedCaps, NULL);
  char *c = gst_caps_to_string(supportedCaps); 
  printf("%s\n",c); 

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to get supported resolutions? Should I use different plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this element, but in GStreamer the resolutions normally won't be available to your code until the element is placed in a pipeline and the pipeline is "played".  Then the elements are activated and connect and make info available.

Hate to link and run, but you may want to start here.

https://gitorious.org/gstreamer-camerabin2/gst-plugins-bad/source/28540988b25f493274762d394c55a4beded5e428:tests/examples/camerabin2

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used camerabin2 but I strongly suggest to use GstDeviceMonitor. By enabling GstDeviceMonitor, you can access all devices that is connected to PC. Not also microphone,speakers but also cameras. Furthermore, you can access whole information of camera devices like resolution, supported formats, fps and etc.

You will use:

```
GList* devices = gst_device_monitor_get_devices(mMonitor);
```

Then, you need to extract information from GList*. I cannot give the whole code because of company policies. I just give you the clue.

Suggested references about code of GstDeviceMonitor 
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstdevicemonitor.html?gi-language=c